# Why do I not get the "Cross-thread operation not valid" error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, exception

I use a BackgroundWorker and do this:

```
private void loadNewAsyncToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = "RunWorkerAsync()";
    backgroundWorkerLoading.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void backgroundWorkerLoading_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    UnsafeThreadMethod("hello");
    EvenUnsaferThreadMethod();
}
```

And now the two methods.

```
private void UnsafeThreadMethod(string text)
{
    toolStripLabelRssFeedData.Text = text;
}

private void EvenUnsaferThreadMethod()
{
    panelLoading.Visible = true;
}
```

I don't understand why `UnsafeThreadMethod` doesn't throw the following exception but `EvenUnsaferThreadMethod` does.

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'panelLoading' accessed from a thread other than the > thread it was created on.

According to the message it's because `toolStripLabelRssFeedData` was created on the same thread but it wasn't.

I thought that I can't call controls created by the main thread and have to use the `ProgressChanged` event. What's going on?

And I have a second question. What is the advantage of doing it like this when I can use `ProgressChanged`? What should I do?

```
private void EvenUnsaferThreadMethod()
{
    if (panelLoading.InvokeRequired)
    {
        panelLoading.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { EvenUnsaferThreadMethod(); }));
    }
    else
    {
        panelLoading.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the first question:

- the cross-thread exception is deliberately thrown in Debug mode. This means there is (conditional) code checking on InvokeRequired built into most of the GUI controls. Like the Panel.
- Apparently the ToolstripLabel does not make this check. Since it does not derive from Control that could be because it is outside the scope of this safety net.

Since the standard disclaimer "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe" applies to the ToolstripLabel I would just go with the normal InvokeRequired logic when setting the Text.

Comment: I think this answer addresses what the OP was asking which was why a clearly looking unsafe call was not throwing an exception. It all revolves around the fact that the ToolStripLabel does not derive from Control and is therefor not checking thread safety. It just happens to work, but as other have pointed out, you can't count on that to stay true forever.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, I am not entirely sure, but a review from online seems to show that sometimes this will not throw an exception, but it will not update the label. Is that the case here? Is your label being updated along with having no exception?

However, I can answer you second question right now. The `ProgressChanged` event is meant for exactly what it sounds like. It is supposed to be called to let the UI thread know the status of the backgroundworker so that it can update itself appropriately. The original calling thread (UI in this case) is the one that is used for the `ProgressChanged`, so when it updates it does not need to call `Invoke`. But, this should really only be done for showing the progress of a background worker.

Now, if it is not an update that you are trying to pass to the calling method, then I would suggest just passing your return data back through the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. This passes all of your final data back up to the original (UI) thread, so that it can update the UI without any need for an `Invoke`.

So, yes your call to `Invoke` will work, though. However, understanding what each of the other events are for can help you understand why to use one way over another. Maybe a `ProgressChanged` event fits better? It can also declutter your code from having unnecessary invokes.

**Update to first q**

I still cannot find anything about the toolstrip not needing the invoke. In fact I am finding the opposite using google searches like "toolstriplabel no cross thread exception" or "toolstriplabel invoke", etc. However, as henk mentioned, the toolstriplabel doesn't inherit from control so that might explain why no invoke is required.  However, my suggestion is to assume that it will act like any other UI control and make sure it is updated on the UI thread to be safe. **do not rely on quirks**. Better safe than sorry, you never know if things like this might change, especially since it is logically a UI item to most..,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the first question: yes, it will update the label just fine. Your answer to my second question cleared things up a lot. I think in my case `RunWorkerCompleted` is the way to go.

Comment: Glad to help. I updated my answer to give my opinion on the label after further research

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of your *second*  choice is that it *works* :)

All UI elements are created on main UI thread and, what is more important from this question perspective, is that can be *acessed only within that thread*.

This is the reason why your *first* case fails and that is the reason your *second* case will work. `Invoke()...` will redirect required merhod call to the main UI thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You said `UnsafeThreadMethod` should not work because the UI stuff is on a different thread but somehow it does and that's what I don't understand. Also, the last question was if it is better to use the Invoke stuff or `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` (which would work because they are back on the right thread).

Comment: That the first case *sometimes* works sounds strange to me. What about the second case: considering that in your method you access UI element, you *have to* use `Invoke` in order to redirect the call to UI thread. It can not work in other way.

Comment: Somehow it does bcause the behavior is not determinate. It can break at will, at service pack, at hotfix.

Comment: I never till now met a case when it worked, but even if there is, it's definitely is **not** something to relay on. Always redirect *esplicitly* to UI thread. Unless it's not built-in into the framework itself to dtermine the cross thread call and redirect to UI thread automatically, under the hood.