# Why can I access forecolor property from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

... Or to put it another way, this (truncated) winforms code throws the expected 'unable to access control on a different thread exception':

```
Label label1 = new Label();    
tickTimer.Elapsed += tickTimer_Elapsed;
void tickTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "New text";
}
```

But this code doesnt:

```
Label label1 = new Label();    
tickTimer.Elapsed += tickTimer_Elapsed;
void tickTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Whats going on? As far as i was aware you couldnt access controls on the 'GUI' thread, from  a background thread. My timer class is the System.Timers.Timer timer, rather than the single threaded winforms version.

**EDIT 1**

Reading the two links from LarsTech below, confirms that this check is only made on classes that derive from control. For both posters, this was not the case. Im prepared to concede that im definitely missing something, but Label *does* derive from control, and the properties im setting are direct members of the Label class, not 'transitive' properties.

**EDIT 2**

On closer inspection... it looks like there are only certain properties that result in a call to `Control.Handle` that go on to trigger the thread checking process. `Text` is one of them, `ForeColor` isnt. OK. This does lead on to another question, which i have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329313/why-do-certain-properties-on-a-control-have-a-higher-priority).

Comment: See [Why do I not get the “Cross-thread operation not valid” error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9758876/719186) and [Updating UI Controls in BackgroundWorker DoWork event does not throw cross thread exception](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f432a0ec-ce62-4b73-a772-f3184c4c2d92/updating-ui-controls-in-backgroundworker-dowork-event-does-not-throw-cross-thread-exception?forum=clr)

Comment: Aha, i was surprised this didnt come up as a dupe, just didnt word it right.